# How to pass variables to an Apollo Mutation for Graphene?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, graphene-python

I'm currently trying to switch from an Apollo server in nodejs to a Graphene server, but I'm having an issue while mutating.

## Client side handling

```
const GeneratedForm = Form.create()(IngredientCategoryForm)

const createCategoryMut = gql`
   mutation createCategoryMut($name: String) {
   createCategory(name:$name) {
      category {
        name
      }
   }
}
`

const createCategoryWithApollo = graphql(createCategoryMut)(GeneratedForm)
export { createCategoryWithApollo as CategoryForm }
```

[image]

[image]

I'm mutating this way :

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {

const {
  mutate
} = this.props

e.preventDefault()
this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
  if (!err) {
    mutate({
      variables: { name: 'myName' }
    })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log('got data', data);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('there was an error sending the query', error);
      })
  }})
}
```

## server side Mutation

class CreateCategory(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        name = graphene.String()

```
category = graphene.Field(lambda: Category)

def mutate(self, info, name='toto'):
    category = Category(name=name)
    return CreateCategory(category=category)
```

Comment: The problem occurs server side, I edited the description

Comment: did you solve this? I found https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/636 which looks like your question, and it refers to a solution in a repo that no longer exists. I'm having the same problem, would love to know if you solved it.